# Rotating bonesssssssssssss

Tags: bones

[image][image]***I have 3 bones for a tongue that have the inherit rotation turned off. I still need these bones to also follow the rotation of the head control aswell. How can I accomplish this.***

Comment: okay I figured it out. I activated the inherit rotation which allows it to rotate with the head. Then added a copy rotation to the base tongue to the jaw bone and it works perfectly.

Comment: Great job, man!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions:
You could parent the tongue bones to the head bone, or you could try the copy rotation bone constraint.

Comment: the tongue bones base is parented to the jaw and the jaw rotates perfectly with the head control. When I try to use copy rotation it doesnt allow the tongue bones to rotate.